# Add model object to cookie in Django

Tags: django, object, cookies

I have a model

```
class Journals(models.Model):
    JOURNAL_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Journal_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Journal_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
```

which I am trying to add to a cookie and then retrieve in other views. I am doing this as follows

```
journal = request.COOKIES.get('journal')

if journal:
    from_cookie = True
else:
    journal = get_object_or_404(Journals, Journal_slug=journal_slug)
    from_cookie = False

template = [...]

template_context = {
    ...
    'journal': journal,
    'from_cookie': from_cookie,
    ...
}

response = render(request, template, template_context)
response.set_cookie('journal', value=journal)
return response
```

It seems however that only the Journal_name is added to the cookie rather than the full object. This way I end up having no access to any of its other fields. How do I get so that the full journal object is added and retrieved instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use cookies directly. Store things in the session.

Secondly, don't try and store model objects anyway. Store the ID, and retrieve the object via that ID when you need to:

```
request.session['journal_id'] = journal.pk
```

...

```
journal = Journal.objects.get(pk=request.session['journal_id'])
```

Comment: Is this not inefficient with respect to database queries or am I over-thinking this?

Comment: you are definitly over-thinking it.